# PHP Drop Down Multi Select

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am new to the world of coding and PHP. Having picked up some of the basics, I have put a form together. I'm sure there are much efficient ways to code a page however seeing I have put something together with what I have learnt so far, I am having troubling getting past on select a multi-select dropdown after the user has posted the page i.e. to remember what the user selected. Here is my entire code.

```
<?php
//Process form variables

//Validate if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Validate if the form elements were completed
    $fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
    $lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
    $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? $_POST['updates'] : '';
    $media = isset($_POST['media']) ? $_POST['media'] : '';
    $comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';

    //Place error messages in an array
    $errormsg = array();

    if(empty($fname)) {
            $errormsg[0] = 'Please specify your first name. It\'s blank.';
        }

    if(empty($lname)) {
            $errormsg[1] = 'Please specify your last name. It\'s blank.';
        }

    if(empty($email)) {
            $errormsg[2] = 'Please provide an email address. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($gender)) {
        $errormsg[3] = 'Please select a gender. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($updates)) {
        $errormsg[4] = 'Please select how we can contact you. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($media)) {
        $errormsg[5] = 'Please select where you heard about us. It\'s blank.';  
    }

    if(empty($comments)) {
        $errormsg[6] = 'Please tell us what you think of us. It\'s blank.';
    }

    //Return list of error messages
    foreach($errormsg as $errormsg) {
        echo $errormsg .  '<br />';
    }

    //Debug
    print_r($_POST['media']);
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Registration Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Sample Registration Form</h2>

            <form name="registration" method="post" action="registration.php">
                <div>
                    First Name:  <br />
                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['fname'])) { echo $fname; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Last Name: <br />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['lname'])) { echo $lname ; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Email Address: <br />
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['email'])) { echo $email; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Gender: <br />
                    <?php
                    //Generate gender array
                    $gender = array('male', 'female');
                    $countgender = count($gender);

                    for($start=0;$start < $countgender;$start=$start+1) {

                        $status = '';

                        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                            if($_POST['gender'][0] == $gender[$start]) {
                                $status = 'checked';
                                // echo $gender[$start];
                            }
                        }

                        $genderform = '<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="'. $gender[$start] . '" '. $status. '>' . $gender[$start];
                        echo $genderform;

                    }                       

                        // foreach($gender as $gender) {

                            // $status = '';

                            // if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                                // if($_POST['gender'][0] == $gender) {
                                    // $status = 'checked';
                                // }
                            // }

                            // $genderform = '<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="' .$gender . '" ' . $status .'>'. $gender . '';
                            // echo $genderform;
                        // }
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Would you like to receive updates from us? <br />
                    <?php
                    $updates = array(0 => 'newsletter', 1 => 'email', 2 => 'sms');

                    foreach($updates as $updatekeys => $updatevalues) {

                        $status = '';

                        if(!empty($_POST['updates'][$updatevalues]) == $updatevalues) {
                            $status = 'checked';
                            // echo $_POST['updates'][$updatevalues];

                        }

                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="updates[' . $updatevalues . ']" value="'. $updatevalues. '" '. $status . '>'.$updatevalues;
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>

                <div>
                    How did you hear about us? <br />

                    <select name="media[]" multiple>
                    <?php

                        $media = array(0 => 'internet', 1 => 'pamphlet', 2 => 'brochure');

                        foreach($media as $mediakey => $mediavalue) {

                            $mediaform = '<option value="'. $mediavalue . '">'.$mediavalue.'</option>';
                            echo $mediaform;

                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Tell us what you think: <br />
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="10"><?php if(!empty($_POST['comments'])) { echo $comments; } ?></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Guys, I have updated my code to reflect some of the suggestions below. Let me know if the page is better coded. I have not included suggestions such as $start++ just because I am trying to understand what it means. I love to make coding as short as possible but seeing that I am just learning, best to get a good foundation.

```
<?php
//Initialize session
session_start();

//Generate session id
echo session_id() . '<br />';

//Process form variables

//Validate if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Validate if the form elements were completed
    $fname = isset($_POST['fname']) ? $_POST['fname'] : '';
    $lname = isset($_POST['lname']) ? $_POST['lname'] : '';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
    $updates = isset($_POST['updates']) ? $_POST['updates'] : '';
    $media = isset($_POST['media']) ? $_POST['media'] : '';
    $comments = isset($_POST['comments']) ? $_POST['comments'] : '';

    //Place error messages in an array
    $errormsg = array();

    if(empty($fname)) {
            $errormsg[0] = 'Please specify your first name. It\'s blank.';
        }

    if(empty($lname)) {
            $errormsg[1] = 'Please specify your last name. It\'s blank.';
        }

    if(empty($email)) {
            $errormsg[2] = 'Please provide an email address. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($gender)) {
        $errormsg[3] = 'Please select a gender. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($updates)) {
        $errormsg[4] = 'Please select how we can contact you. It\'s blank.';
    }

    if(empty($media)) {
        $errormsg[5] = 'Please select where you heard about us. It\'s blank.';  
    }

    if(empty($comments)) {
        $errormsg[6] = 'Please tell us what you think of us. It\'s blank.';
    }

    //Return list of error messages
    foreach($errormsg as $errormsg) {
        echo $errormsg .  '<br />';
    }

    //Debug
    // print_r($_POST['media']);
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Registration Form</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Sample Registration Form</h2>

            <form name="registration" method="post" action="registration.php">
                <div>
                    First Name:  <br />
                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['fname'])) { echo $fname; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Last Name: <br />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['lname'])) { echo $lname ; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Email Address: <br />
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST['email'])) { echo $email; } ?>">
                </div>

                <div>
                    Gender: <br />
                    <?php
                    //Generate gender array
                    $gender = array('male', 'female');
                    $countgender = count($gender);

                    for($start=0;$start < $countgender;$start=$start+1) {

                        $status = '';

                        if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) {
                            $status = in_array($gender[$start], $_POST['gender']) ? 'checked' : '';
                        }

                        $genderform = '<input type="radio" name="gender[]" value="'. $gender[$start] . '" '. $status. '>' . $gender[$start];
                        echo $genderform;

                    }                       

                    ?>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Would you like to receive updates from us? <br />
                    <?php
                    $updates = array(0 => 'newsletter', 1 => 'email', 2 => 'sms');

                    foreach($updates as $updatekeys => $updatevalues) {

                        $status = '';

                        if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['updates'])) {
                            $status = in_array($updatevalues, $_POST['updates']) ? 'checked' : '';
                        }

                        // if(!empty($_POST['updates'][$updatevalues]) == $updatevalues) {
                            // $status = 'checked';
                            // echo $_POST['updates'][$updatevalues];

                        // }

                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="updates[' . $updatevalues . ']" value="'. $updatevalues. '" '. $status . '>'.$updatevalues;
                    }

                    ?>
                </div>

                <div>
                    How did you hear about us? <br />

                    <select name="media[]" multiple>
                    <?php

                        $media = array(0 => 'internet', 1 => 'pamphlet', 2 => 'brochure');

                        foreach($media as $mediakey => $mediavalue) {

                            $status = in_array($mediavalue,$_POST['media'])? 'selected' : '';

                            $mediaform = '<option value="'. $mediavalue . '" '. $status .'>'.$mediavalue.'</option>';
                            echo $mediaform;

                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Tell us what you think: <br />
                    <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="10"><?php if(!empty($_POST['comments'])) { echo $comments; } ?></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I submit the form, the multi dropdown/listbox does not retain its values. I have tried for, while and do loops to no avail.

Comment: you need to echo selected="selected" in the option that was  selected, and then returned in the post array

Comment: In general, I think that it is ok - but I think that it will be better to split it on smaller chunks you have questions about and work on each of them separately - this question is already answered so nobody really pay attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in_array function to check whether the current $mediavalue in the array of selected $media - but you need to select another name for array with media sources, because it overwrites the $media variable with user selection. For example:

```
 $mediaTypes = array(0 => 'internet', 1 => 'pamphlet', 2 => 'brochure');
 foreach($mediaTypes as $mediakey => $mediavalue) {
   $mediaform = '<option value="'. $mediavalue . '" '
     . (in_array($mediavalue, $media) ? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $mediavalue.'</option>';
   echo $mediaform;
 }
```

There are a few recommended minor modifications to you code as well:

1. you do not need to use numbers in array - it duplicates the default behavior, so $mediaTypes = array(0 => 'internet', 1 => 'pamphlet', 2 => 'brochure'); can be just $mediaTypes = array('internet', 'pamphlet', 'brochure');
2. when gender is not set, $_POST['gender'] causes notice "Undefined index: gender".
3. $start=$start+1 can be compacted to $start++;
4. it is better to reuse the variables with user inputs instead of accessing $_POST directly

Comment: Thanks AlexAtNet. @magma helped with code that was easier to follow however as mentioned I have no idea what in_array does, when to use it, etc. Would you mind elaborating on your code?

This was @magma's example

`foreach($media as $mediakey => $mediavalue) {

    $selected=in_array($mediavalue,$_POST['media'])?"selected":"";

    $mediaform = '<option '.$selected.' value="'. $mediavalue . '">'.$mediavalue.'</option>';

    echo $mediaform;

}`

Comment: Yes, I know I get the error Undefined index. I was planning to rectify that after solving the issue of remembering what the user selected for the list box. Thanks for the advise.

Any reason you suggested it better to reuse variables?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey : AlexAtNet's code is identical, and he also provided important recommendations. "in_array" checks whether a given value is included in an existing array. In our case, if it is, we're adding the 'selected' keyword to the html tag, so that it stays selected when rendered.

Comment: @magma. Thanks. I understand how ternary operators work. Think they call them operators but am unsure how in_array works. I don't quite follow it. Correct me if I am wrong.

$selected = in_array($value I am looking to match(a), in the value in here(b)) ? 'selected : '';

Hence if I the value (a) is found in (b), the statement will returned 'selected'. If it returns false, it will return ''.

Is that right?

Comment: @magma - Sorry I was unable to split the acceptance of the answer between AlexAtNet and you but thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @magma/AlexAtNet - I was just updating the rest of my code e.g.

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$status = in_array($updatevalues, $_POST['updates']) ? 'checked' : '';
}`

and I noticed unlike 

`$status = in_array($mediavalue,$_POST['media'])? 'selected' : '';` 


I have had to validate if the form was processed. If I don't I get an error message that states that there is an undefined index. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($media as $mediakey => $mediavalue) {

    $selected=in_array($mediavalue,$_POST['media'])?"selected":"";

    $mediaform = '<option '.$selected.' value="'. $mediavalue . '">'.$mediavalue.'</option>';

    echo $mediaform;

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked however I have no idea what in_array does especially with the code construct in your example i.e. $mediavalue,$_POST['media']. 

$status = in_array($mediavalue,$_POST['media'])? 'selected' : '';

Would you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

based on form output of the dropdown, set a $_SESSION['variable'] the do something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['variable'])) {
// if exists
}
else {
// if doesn't exist
}
```

you could even include other elseif statements based on different parameters. Then use else as an error handle.